# Adding ImageView to the Layout programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I want to create images which will go down from the upper part of the screen.

For up to today I have this:

```
ImageView mario = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mario);
TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(0f, 0f, 0, 400);
anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
anim.setDuration(800);
mario.startAnimation(anim);
```

The problems are that I have to set the imageview on the xml file on the layout and this code creates just 1 picture only.

I want to program the app to create a couple of images (for example in a loop) in the upper part of the screen and  have them drop down the screen. (here I use TranslateAnimation here).
I found something like this:

```
ImageView mario = (ImageView) findViewById(R.drawable.mario);
```

But I don't know how to set the position of the ImageView which isn't in the xml file (is it possible?).
I though about creating LinearLayout and add it to the ImageView. But how to add the linearlayout to the existing layout?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can create a layout with something like

```
View view = (View) findViewById(R.layout.current_layout); //the layout you set in `setContentView()`
LinearLayout picLL = new LinearLayout(CurrentActivity.this);
picLL.layout(0, 0, 100, 0);
picLL.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(1000, 60));
picLL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
((ViewGroup) view).addView(picLL);
```

What parameters you pass in `layout()` are obviously going to depend on what you want. Then you can create separate `Views` to add to the `Layout` you just created. But I highly advise reading through the docs to understand what all can be done here.

[ViewGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html)

[View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html)

**Edit**

```
ImageView myImage = new ImageView(this);
picLL.addView(myImage);
//set attributes for myImage;
```

Comment: The last sentence `((ViewGroup) view).addView(picLL);` doesn't work, because of: "Type
ViewGroup cannot be resolved to a type". Also why we don't use the `view`? And the last question - how to add the ImageView to this view?

Comment: The `ViewGroup` allows you to add additionally items to that `View`. You can try just `View` but I don't believe it will work to add things to it but I will check into it when I get a few more minutes. I will edit my answer to add the `ImageView` to the layout

Answer (score 5):

Using following code you can add image dynamically

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 ImageView imageview = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
 RelativeLayout relativelayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
 LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout
 .LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

 // Add image path from drawable folder.
 imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.demo_new_image);
 imageview.setLayoutParams(params); 
 relativelayout.addView(imageview); 

 }
}
```