# Dynamically add ImageView to LinearLayout

Tags: android, imageview, android-linearlayout

I'm attempting to add `ImageViews` to a `LinearLayout` at runtime, but every time I run my app, I get nothing. There is nothing in logcat reporting any errors either, I'm a bit lost...

**XML**

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/guessHolders"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/copyrightText"
    android:background="@color/LightCyan"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:minHeight="45dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp" >

</LinearLayout>
```

and the code behind it:

```
    LinearLayout guessHolders = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.guessHolders);      

    for(int i=0; i<Globals.mUser.getLevel().getSolution().length(); i++)
    {
        EmptyLetter tmp = new EmptyLetter(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams parms = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(40, 40, 1);
        tmp.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        tmp.setLayoutParams(parms);
        currentEmpties.add(tmp);

        guessHolders.addView(tmp);
    }

    guessHolders.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
```

All I'm seeing is a blank LinearLayout. Ideally, I want the imageviews to be side-by-side, but I can't fathom it.

I've checked out loads of similar questions, but none of the answers are helping. Although I did find out that I required LayoutParams, which I didn't have before, and that I had to setOrientation, from [Adding ImageView to the Layout programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15097950/adding-imageview-to-the-layout-programmatically), but still nothing shows up. :(

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You'll have to include the code for `EmptyLetter`, if it's extending `ImageView` then when is the source set? You set the orientation on the `LinearLayout` in xml so no need to set it again.

Answer (score 0):

Change your LinearLayout. I hope your LInearLayout is within RelativeLayout.
Why android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" both are specified?