# How To create Dynamic Imageview in android studio where user enter data as per requirements

Tags: android, android-imageview

How to create a dynamic image view in an android studio where user enters data as per requirements.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15097950/adding-imageview-to-the-layout-programmatically

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to achieve that, the first looks like the following:

```
// user entered the requared data
// ...
// dynamically create an imageView, context it is a reference to your activity
// 
ImageView iv = new ImageView(context)
// set an image to the imageView:
iv.setImageResource(R.id.my_pic)
//or
iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
```

The second way is instead of creation an ImageView dynamically you can add it to your xml layout and set it's visibility to "GONE", and then when user entered the requared data you simple change the visibility of the imageView to "VISIBLE".